# Finding the values of a scalar function on a 3D grid which correspond to the direction of slowest increase

Tags: matlab, optimization, vector, minimum

I have some scalar function F(x,y,z) defined on a grid in 3D space, and there is a minimum of F somewhere in the array. Example code to generate such a function, and locate the coordinates of the minimum, is given below:

```matlab
x = linspace(-10,80,100);
y = linspace(-20,5,100);
z = linspace(-10,10,100);
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(x,y,z);

F = some_scalar_function(X, Y, Z);

% Find the minimum of the function on the grid
[minval,ind] = min(F(:));
[ii,jj,kk] = ind2sub(size(F),ind);
xmin = x(jj);
ymin = y(ii);
zmin = z(kk);

figure;isosurface(X,Y,Z,F,minval+100)

% Some sample scalar function (assume it is given on the grid, and the analytic form not known)
function F = some_scalar_function(X, Y, Z)

F = (X-6).^2 + 10*(Y+2).^2 + 10*Z.^2 + 5*X.*Y;

end
```

I would like to obtain a vector of F values from the grid along some new direction (let's call it r) which corresponds to the direction of *slowest increase* of the function F, i.e starting from the minimum and "walking" outwards. I would also like to obtain the corresponding values of the coordinate r as well. I have tried to explain what I mean in the figure below:

[image]

Taking a path along any direction other than r should lead to a steeper increase in F, and is therefore not the correct route. Can anyone show how this can be done in Matlab? Thanks!

---

**EDIT**

After the comments from rahnema1 and Ander Biguri, I have run the command

```matlab
[Gmag,Gazimuth,Gelevation] = imgradient3(F);
```

Taking a look at a plane through z=0, the function F(x,y,z=0) itself looks like the following:

[image]

and the outputs from `imgradient3()` look like this (again, only a single plane from the resulting full 3D arrays):

[image]

How can I obtain the line cut corresponding to path of slowest increase as a function of r from these? (still bearing in mind they are 3D arrays, and the direction is not necessarily constrained to the z=0 plane).

Comment: But, does R change in direction then, with each step (unless F is linear)? How big is each step? Perhaps explaining the real world problem is a place where you would find better help in this case, the abstraction makes me wonder if you are simply approaching the problem wrong.

Comment: @Ander Biguri Yes good question, apologies I did not include that detail. The direction of r will indeed vary (slowly) as we move further away from the minimum, but around the minimum it can be approximated as linear. The physical problem is that F is a potential energy landscape, and I am looking to find the harmonic oscillation frequency of a particle along the "natural" direction of the potential. Once the 1D line cut is found, I can then simply fit a parabolic function to extract the frequency.

Comment: So, you are looking at the minimum energy path, I see. With an analytic function, you'd for example compute the directional derivative and choose the minimum one. You can do the same here. I suspect you'd need to play with the neighborhood size for that directional derivative, as in a discrete grid with only 1 neighbor, the directions are limited. If you are good with that level of discretization error, then the first order directional derivatives are very easy to compute (just the difference between adjacent pixels, accounting for their distances).

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thanks. Do you mean go pixel by pixel, calculating a directional derivative each time and choosing the smallest in order to decide where to go next? So, finding the minimum energy path by traversing point by point?

Comment: Have you tried [imgradient3](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgradient3.html)? I believe it implements the methods that is mentioned in @AnderBiguri 's comments.

Comment: @teeeeee yes! thats right

Comment: @rahnema1 I was not aware of this function. It may do the job. I assume I need to simply use the command ```[Gmag,Gazimuth,Gelevation] = imgradient3(F)```, but then  could you provide an example of how I can obtain the 1D cut from these resulting matrices?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Edited the OP to include some outputs from imgradient3().

Comment: I am not sure what rahnema meant here, as the gradient is the direction of the maximum change. With `imgradient3` you will get that, the direction of maximum change, but you want the opposite. In any case, were you interested in the maximum, the azimuth and elevation tells you the direction of the gradient.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I think your suggestion of finding directional derivatives and walking through the array according to the minimum one is what I need. Could you provide an example in an answer?

Comment: Sorry, don't have time now to do so. If you know the minimum position, then its just a loop, check all neighbour distances, select minimum, keep going.

Comment: If you don't want to use loop you may need graph algorithms like allshortestpaths or graydist using the min point as start node and surface of a sphere centred in the start node as taget nodes. I may provide an answer possibly after a few days.

Comment: @rahnema1 Thanks. I am happy to use a loop, no problem. I am just not sure how to calculate directional derivative along every direction for every neighbour along the path... Although I would be happy with any answer which leads to the right solution. Thanks!

Comment: The loop can be as complicated as the shortest path algorithm! See the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a sphere that its center is the position of the minimum point of `F`.
For each point on the surface of the sphere compute the shortest path to the center point. use [`imerode`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html) to find the surface of the sphere and use [`shortestpathtree`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.shortestpathtree.html) to compute the tree of shortest paths.
Gradient magnitude is set as the difficulty of path traversal. Use [`imgradient3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgradient3.html) to calculate the gradient magnitude.
The path between the surface point with the minimum distance to the center , `path1`, is considered the direction of slowest increase of the function `F`.
But `path1` is the half of the path. Other half ,`path2`, is computed by eliminating the sub-tree that contains the first surface point and again computing the shortest path tree using the resulting graph. The function `im2col3` is defined for converting the 3D array to graph data structure.
Here is the non tested code:

```
% im2col for 3D image
function col = im2col3 (im)
  col = zeros(prod(size(im)-2), 26);
  n = 1;
  for kk = 1:3
    for jj = 1:3
      for ii = 1:3
        if ~(ii == 2 && jj == 2 && kk == 2)
          col(:, n) = reshape(im(ii:end-(3-ii), jj:end-(3-jj), kk:end-(3-kk)),[],1);
          n = n + 1;
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

% gradient magnitude
[Gmag,~,~] = imgradient3(F);

% convert array to graph
idx = reshape(1:numel(F), size(F));
t = im2col3(idx);
w = Gmag(t);
s = repmat(reshape(idx(2:end-1,2:end-1,2:end-1),[],1), size(t, 2));
G = graph(s, t, w);

% form the sphere
[~, sphere_center] = min(F(:));
[r, c, z] = ind2sub(size(F), sphere_center);
sphere_radius_2 = min([r c z])  ^ 2;
sphere_logical = ((1:size(F, 1)).'- r) .^ 2 ...
               + ((1:size(F, 2))- c) .^ 2 ...
               + (reshape(1:size(F, 3), 1, 1, [])- z) .^ 2 ...
               < sphere_radius_2;

se = strel('cube',3);
sphere_surface = xor(imerode(sphere_logical, se), sphere_logical);
sphere_nodes = idx(sphere_surface);

% compute the half of the path
[T, D] = shortestpathtree(G, sphere_center, sphere_nodes,'OutputForm','cell');
[mn1, im1] = min(D);

path1 = T{im1};

% eliminate the sub-tree
subtree_root = path1(2);
subtree_nodes = bfsearch(T, subtree_root);
G1 = rmnodes (G, subtree_nodes);
sphere_nodes = setdiff (sphere_nodes, subtree_nodes);

% computing other half
[T1, D1] = shortestpathtree(G1, sphere_center, sphere_nodes,'OutputForm','cell');
[mn2, im2] = min(D1);

path2 = T1{im2};
```